# C# Winform application couldn't run when Window startup

Tags: c#, winforms

everyone
I have a problem with my application. I make an event that when I tick to a checkbox it will run when Window startup and I save this setting in a XML file. But it doesn't work and Window show me a message error "Stop working". Does anyone know what did I do wrong? I try to resolve it but it still. Thanks a lot. Here is my code:

```
private RegistryKey registrykeyApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", true);
private void checkBoxKhoidongcungwin_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.checkBoxKhoidongcungwin.Checked)
        {
            if(this.registrykeyApp.GetValue("ViKey") == null)
                this.registrykeyApp.SetValue("ViKey", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString(),RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);

        }
        else
        {
            this.registrykeyApp.DeleteValue("ViKey", false);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a try/catch and find out what the error is... or if debugging, why not tell us. What is the error?

Comment: I guess it's an 'access denied' error, try running your application with administrator privilege.

Comment: You must improve the unhandled exception handling in your program so it does not just bomb with a "Stopped working" message.  Write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  Log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  Now you can tell us what *really* went wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will help me much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That registry key cannot be accessed from an application that is not running with elevated privileges since viruses, etc could use it to hijack computers. Unfortunately when access is denied you often get generic errors that aren't obvious.

Right click on your exe and run it as administrator and it should work. If so you can add an application manifest to your project to always request the elevated privileges automatically, without manually right clicking.

http://www.samlogic.net/articles/manifest.htm

Comment: If you elevate the process, does the intended user get the startup reg key?